Laravel Horizon - Gracefully Wait and Exit
artisan horizon:terminate  --wait
Does not actually work as documented.  The supervisor sends SIGTERM but the workers will abort running jobs.   There are a number of discussions on github about this.
Is there an alternative way to determine what horizon is currently running on a given supervisor node?  I can simply write the script to wait and exit our instance if so.
